# How to do a correct Redirect with (msal) msal-browser?

Tags: typescript, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

When I am implementing an authorisation mechanisme with with msal-browser using redirect and not popup I seem to run into strange behaviors

Problem 1 : I get unwanted parameters in my url.
Problem 2 : I do not get to see my protected content. However when I push the login button once more it brings me to the protected content.

I think it has something to do with the redirect or the way that my application after login handles the logged account??

I am trying to do a ssoSilent and if there is msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError I do a loginRedirect.

[image]

The code that containt authentication logic. Im using static class and method.

Any suggestions?

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";
import AppSettings from './../appSettings';

export default class SpaAuthService {
    private static clientId: string = AppSettings.clientId;
    private static authority: string = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + AppSettings.tenant;//+ ".onmicrosoft.com/B2X_1_DetermineIsTestUser"; //https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
    public static userIsAuthenticated: boolean = false;
    public static userDisplayName: string = "";
    public static userName: string = "";
    public static uiUpdateCallback: any;
    public static isTestUser: boolean;
    public static accountId: string;
    public static account: msal.AuthenticationResult;

    private static msalConfig: msal.Configuration = {
        auth: {
            clientId: SpaAuthService.clientId,
            authority: SpaAuthService.authority,
            redirectUri: "https://localhost:44301/",
            postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:44301/"
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false
        }
    };;



    // Create an instance of PublicClientApplication
    private static publicApplication: msal.PublicClientApplication = new msal.PublicClientApplication(SpaAuthService.msalConfig);;

    private static silentRequest: msal.SilentRequest = {
        scopes: AppSettings.apiScopes,
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:44301/"
    };


    static attemptSillentLogin = async () => {
        var userInfo: msal.AccountInfo = SpaAuthService.publicApplication.getAllAccounts()[0];
        if (userInfo) {
            console.log(userInfo);
            SpaAuthService.userName = userInfo.username;
            SpaAuthService.userDisplayName = userInfo.name;
            SpaAuthService.userIsAuthenticated = true;
            SpaAuthService.uiUpdateCallback();
        }
    }

    static login = async () => {


        SpaAuthService.publicApplication.ssoSilent(SpaAuthService.silentRequest)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response !== null) {
                    SpaAuthService.userName = response.account.username;
                    SpaAuthService.userDisplayName = response.account.name;
                    SpaAuthService.userIsAuthenticated = true;
                    SpaAuthService.uiUpdateCallback();
                } else {

                    /**
                     * See here for more info on account retrieval: 
                     * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/Accounts.md
                     */

                    const currentAccounts = SpaAuthService.publicApplication.getAllAccounts();

                    if (currentAccounts.length === 0) {
                        return;
                    } else if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
                        // Add your account choosing logic here
                        console.warn("Multiple accounts detected.");
                    } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
                        SpaAuthService.userName = currentAccounts[0].username;
                        SpaAuthService.userDisplayName = currentAccounts[0].name;
                        SpaAuthService.userIsAuthenticated = true;
                        SpaAuthService.uiUpdateCallback();
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn("silent token acquisition fails. acquiring token using redirect");
                if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    SpaAuthService.publicApplication.loginRedirect();
                    }
                } else {
                    console.warn(error);
                }
            });

    }

    static logout = () => {

        const logoutRequest = {
            account: SpaAuthService.publicApplication.getAccountByUsername(SpaAuthService.userName)
        };
        SpaAuthService.userName = "";
        SpaAuthService.userDisplayName = "";
        SpaAuthService.userIsAuthenticated = false;
        SpaAuthService.publicApplication.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);

    }
}
```